# non-static variable v_var cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static-variables

I have a class called "setup" that has a method that returns a string

```
public class Setup{
    public String getPW(){ return "pAssWord";}
}
```

I imported "Setup", tried to assign it to private static String, and then the system throws this error.

```
public class Something {

    private Setup v_var= new Setup();
    private static String password = v_var.getPW();
}
```

It accepts the hardcoded string, but not method called String.
Can someone explain me a logic behind this?

Comment: `password` is `static` but `v_var` is not.  You either need to make `v_var` `static` or `password` not `static`. I'm not sure I see the point of what you're doing, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_v` is an instance variable. Each instance of your class would have a different value for this var. `password` is a static member, and is the same for all instances of your class. That's why you can't assign to it a value that is specific to an instance.